# PostgreSQL - Base Backups and PITR

Tags: postgresql, backup, write-ahead-logging

According to the [PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/continuous-archiving.html) for producing *Standalone Hot Backups*:

> These are backups that cannot be used for point-in-time recovery, yet
> are typically much faster to backup and restore than pg_dump dumps.

It seems that all that is required to produce these kinds of backups is to use *pg_basebackup* utility and include the **-X** option, which essentially includes the required WAL files necessary to start the cluster. Why can't these backups be used for PITR? If I don't start this backup immediately, shouldn't I be able to place it in recovery mode and allow it to restore up to any point after the backup was created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that the wording is confusing.

A `pg_basebackup` taken with `-X stream` can of course be taken as a basis for point-in-time recovery.

I think the assumption here is that you take a `pg_basebackup` but do not have WAL archiving configured. Then the backup contains just the WAL segments required to recover to the end of the backup and reach a consistent state, but you don't have the WAL required to recover beyond that point.

Answer (score -1):

That seems like a doc bug, in that `-X` needs an argument, and it doesn't clarify what options you are supposedly using for it.  The description it gives would seem to apply to either `fetch` or to `stream`, but not apply to `none`.

You can use such a basebackup generated with `-X stream` or `-X fetch` for PITR as long as also have a WAL archive.  <s>I think the assumption here is that you would not use those options if you were keeping a wal archive anyway.  I think that is a bad assumption.  I like my backups to be as flexible as possible.  If your backup includes the minimal set of its own WAL, then you can either restore it standalone for a single time point, or you can use it to seed PITR with the wal archive.  This seems useful to me.</s>  Actually this is your bad assumption, not the doc's.  You have juxtaposed two different parts of the docs, talking about two different things (`pg_dump` and `pg_basebackup`), as if they were talking about the same thing.